# Angular $on function with this keyword

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
(function(){

    var eateryControllers=angular.module('eateryControllers',[]);

    eateryControllers.controller('MainController',function($scope){
        var mainCtrl=this;
        mainCtrl.$on('$viewContentLoaded',function(){
            console.log("view loaded");
        })
    });

})();
```

this caused an **error**: mainCtrl.$on is not a function. Earlier versions did this by injecting $scope. Cant we do this using 'this' keyword and 'Controller as' approach like above way

Answer (score 2):

In your case, 'this' refers to the controller and not the $scope. For 'this' to refer to $scope, you would need to be within a $scope method. You need to use:

```
$scope.$on(...)
```

See also: ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers)